# Speeding up Python with C++

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am attempting to speed up a Python script by using ctypes to outsource some of the heavily lifting to C++.

I have this up and running quite nicely with a small example (returning x^2) but now it is time to set up my function in this configuration.

My question is, how would one write this function of Python code nicely in C++ to ensure its as quick as possible, I would hate to think I might not get any speed increase, simply because of my sub-par C++.

```
def shortTermEnergy(frame):
    return sum( [ abs(x)**2 for x in frame ] ) / len(frame)
```

I will be passing `frame` as an array by using `arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(frame))(*frame)` converting it from a list to a nice array for C++

I hope this is the best practice and I am not missing anything glaringly obvious? It's been a *long* time since I wrote any C++.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have gone with this C++ code for the moment, please do let me know if there are ways to improve.

```
#include <cmath>

extern "C" int square(int size, int array[])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int number = array[i];
        int value = (number * number);
        sum = sum + value;
    }

    return floor(sum / size);
}
```

Where `size` is the len() of the array passed from Python.

Comment: Implementations depends how `frame` is represented in your c++ code (native array / stl vector) - not sure that the efficiency will vary that much from one option to another, but there *are* different (shorter / longer) ways of implementing it depending on `frame`'s type.

Comment: It would be a native array I think (I assume that would be best)

Comment: why do you use abs(x)? isn't squaring x sufficient to have a positive value?

Comment: Very good point, I will remove that. I am not the original author of that function and overlooked it.

Comment: A suggestion: I believe python module numpy was created to speed up math operations in python, in your place a would give it a try before rewriting things in C++

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for the suggestion, I will look into using numpy as well and see if it out performs the c++ implementation

Comment: @Brahim, that depends on the domain of `frame`. Python natively supports `complex` numbers. For example, `frame` could be the complex-valued DFT of a real-valued signal, and it's summing the energy in a frequency band. In that case `(frame[i] * frame[i].conjugate()).real` corresponds to `abs(frame[i])**2`, but multiplying by the conjugate is more efficient and more precise. The `conjugate` method is also trivially implemented for Python's real-valued number types.

Comment: to further improve performance you can try multithreading with omp parallel for map reduce like in this example http://chryswoods.com/book/export/html/93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with this:

```
template<class MeanT, class AccumT = MeanT, class IterT>
MeanT mean_squares(IterT start, IterT end) {
  AccumT accum = 0;
  for (IterT it = start; it != end; ++it) {
    accum += *it * *it;
  }
  return accum / (end - start);
}
```

I left out the `abs` since it's not necessary. But it *could* be that the compiler is able to optimise unsigned multiplication better.

Using is like this:

```
double result = mean_squares<double, unsigned long>(array, array + length);
// std::begin(vect), std::end(vect) in case of an STL vector
```

I hope this helps.

**concerning your code:** it's probably OK, though I would make the `sum` and `i` unsigned. You can add `const` to the array parameter type, but the compiler most certainly is able to figure that out on its own.
 Oh, and I think you should remove that `floor`. Integer division does that already.

Comment: I tried several approaches including the op's (just out of curiosity), and this one was by far the fastest. according to relative calculations I've made, the op's code took on my machine about 160-165 µs overall for 10,000 elements, and this example takes about 50! I'll be glad if anyone can explain the huge differences compared to the not so different implementations (after template instanciation).

Comment: Hi daniel, I will look into using your above function. I did take your comments on my own code on board, all of which worked nicely, except making the sum unsigned , this actually gave me different outputs strangely.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not answering your question explicitly, but I think a numpy solution would be a lot easier to realise and can improve the speed almost as good as a C++ snippet:

```
import numpy as np
frame = np.random.random_sample(10000)

def shortTermEnergy(frame):
    return sum( [ abs(x)**2 for x in frame ] ) / len(frame)

>> %timeit shortTermEnergy(frame)
>> 100 loops, best of 3: 4.11 ms per loop


def dot_product(frame):
    return np.dot(frame, frame)/frame.size

>> %timeit dot_product(frame):
>> 10000 loops, best of 3: 19.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: Hey dlenz, this actually made a massive improvement, which is great for such a simple change. C++ still outperformed this method as expected, but it's good to know anyway, cheers